# Pig UDF Class Cast Exception Distributed Cache

Tags: apache-pig

This is my distributed Cache in Pig Implementation:

```
public class Regex extends EvalFunc<String> {
    static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public List<String> getCacheFiles() {
        Path lookup_file = new Path(
                "hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/top");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(1);
        list.add(lookup_file + "#id_lookup");
        return list;
    }

    public void VectorizeData() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("./id_lookup");
        BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while ((line = brd.readLine()) != null) {
            String str[] = line.split("#");
            map.put(str[0], str[1]);
        }
        fr.close();
    }

    private String Regex(Tuple input) throws ExecException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String tweet = (String) input.get(0);
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(map.get(entry.getKey()));
            Matcher m = r.matcher(tweet);
            System.out.println(m.find());
            System.out.println(m.pattern());
            if (m.find() == true) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        VectorizeData();

        return Regex(input);
    }

}
```

Here is the error below once i run this UDF.
Which is mostly got to do with hash map

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at UDF.Regex.Regex(Regex.java:47)
    at UDF.Regex.exec(Regex.java:70)
    at UDF.Regex.exec(Regex.java:1)
```

The hashmap is returning a size of 3 that means its populated.
Please help resolve Class cast exception

Comment: Can you post, or highlight,  the line UDF.Regex.Regex(Regex.java:47)

Comment: String tweet = (String) input.get(0);

Comment: Run a debugger there. It appears the `Tuple` is holding a `HashMap`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Just sorted it out.